# Logic Apps creates Sharepoint file, but gives error message

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In my logic app I have a command to create a file in Sharepoint which it does.  However, it gives this error message even though it creates the file.  The output to the file failed when I was printing xml (which I validated as correct).  However it succeeded in printing JSON.  This is the expression I used to convert the JSON to XML

```
xml(json(outputs('Compose')))
```

With this JSON the Create File worked.

```
{"Results":{"root":[{"PR_ADD1":"","PR_NAME":"JS TEST 
PROPERTY","PR_OWN":"xxx","PR_SNAM":"JS_PROP_1"}, 
{"PR_ADD1":"qqq","PR_NAME":"PROPERTY08","PR_OWN":"SC-CO-001","PR_SNAM":"P- 
 000028"}]}}
```

THis XML caused the create file to fail even though it created a file with this text.

```
<Results><root><PR_ADD1>qqq</PR_ADD1><PR_NAME>PROPERTY08</PR_NAME> 
<PR_OWN>SC-CO-001</PR_OWN><PR_SNAM>P-000028</PR_SNAM></root><root><PR_ADD1> 
</PR_ADD1><PR_NAME>JS TEST PROPERTY</PR_NAME><PR_OWN>xxx</PR_OWN> 
<PR_SNAM>JS_PROP_1</PR_SNAM></root></Results>
```

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "headers": {
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, private",
        "Date": "Fri, 29 Nov 2019 13:16:30 GMT",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=35d7413135aa4903f68e02da1544fd04b13d5423a37ac45ed3f80796d9d90742;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=sharepointonline-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "Content-Length": "838",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "error": {
            "code": 500,
            "source": "logic-apis-northeurope.azure-apim.net",
            "clientRequestId": "6fb65339-4b52-4c86-9636-9494592404eb",
            "message": "BadGateway",
            "innerError": {
                "status": 500,
                "message": "Type 'Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.ObjectModel.SPBlobMetadataResponse' with data contract name 'SPBlobMetadataResponse:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.ObjectModel' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.",
                "source": "sharepointonline-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this worked, but I set a variable equal to the output of the compose3 action and set the value of the create file action to this variable.  Not sure why that made a difference, but it worked.